# Listview freezing while Caching images for thumbnail

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Facing one minor freeze while binding the thumbnail images to the listview. My image is coming from server as base64 format. I need to cache the images permanently and display it in listview. At the time of binding the the images in listview after caching it in SQLite, it is giving minor freeze.

Doing below operations,

Load Listview from Sqlite DB -> Call service to fetch image and cache it in SQLite -> Convert fetched image to thumbnail -> Bind to listview.

Please suggest how can i efficiently cache the images from custom web service.

Comment: Are you converting images to thumbnail in main UI thread? You should use `Task.Run` to run your image conversion on different thread.

Comment: Yes I am using different thread for that. My web service call and DB insert operation is handled by different thread. I am fetching almost 40 thumbnail images and storing to DB before binding to listview one by one. I found this freeze is coming because of DB insert operation. But how can i efficiently cache the images in this case.